# Camel K with Jolt transformer

Tags: apache-camel, apache-camel-k

I am using camel and use JOLT transformer to transform from JSON TO JSON and it works fine when deploying on spring boot or even when using camel as stand-alone. But when trying to switch to Camel-K I am facing some problems, I cant refer to the Jolt template transformation inside the camel route or even add it to the deployment. Anybody have the info on how can I attach the Jolt transformer template to camel K to be able to use it in the route.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the --resource flag to add a resource to the camel-k classpath:

```
kamel run my-integration.groovy --resource=spec.json
```

and then use in in your integration

```
to('jolt:spec.json')
```

we are working on improving the support for resource handling: https://github.com/apache/camel-k/issues/2003

Comment: yes, it works right now. Thanks for your reply.